# Can we use Azure Service Bus Authorization tool ( sbaztool.exe) behind a proxy?

Tags: azure, servicebus

If the answer is yes, how to pass the credentials.

Comment: This tool is just working fine if I have direct internet connection. Having issues running behind a HTTP proxy which requires authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. It was actually developed behind a proxy. You set the namespace name with -n and the key with -k. The key is the management key for the namespace.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Authorization-SBAzTool-6fd76d93

With storeoptions you can save key and namespace so that you don't have to enter them every time.

Comment: This tool is just working fine if I have direct internet connection. Having issues running behind a HTTP proxy which requires authentication.

Comment: In that case you may have to tweak the tool's config file (you'll have to create one) and add the right settings for your proxy using the system.net proxy settings. You can also do that right in the startup code. Here is a general discussion: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318140